# How to incorporate django-tailwind into Dockerized cookiecutter-django project?

Tags: django, docker

Apologies for what is likely a very simple question, I am pretty new to Docker and am struggling to integrate django-tailwind into my docker project, which was created using [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django).

I have tried altering my Dockerfile and local.yml file to follow the Example dockerfiles on the Example app on the [django-tailwind](https://github.com/timonweb/django-tailwind/tree/master/example) github repo but haven't been able make it work. The [instructions](https://django-tailwind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docker.html) beyond the example app are not very detailed.

I have quoted my Dockerfile and local.yml file below; would someone be able to advise on what changes I need to make in order to incorporate django-tailwind, or point me in the direction of information that would help me to do it myself?

Dockerfile:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9-slim-bullseye

# define an alias for the specfic python version used in this file.
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION} as python

# Python build stage
FROM python as python-build-stage

ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=local

# Install apt packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # dependencies for building Python packages
  build-essential \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  libpq-dev

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements .

# Create Python Dependency and Sub-Dependency Wheels.
RUN pip wheel --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels  \
  -r ${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}.txt


# Python 'run' stage
FROM python as python-run-stage

ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=local
ARG APP_HOME=/app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV BUILD_ENV ${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}

WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

# Install required system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  libpq-dev \
  # Translations dependencies
  gettext \
  # cleaning up unused files
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# All absolute dir copies ignore workdir instruction. All relative dir copies are wrt to the workdir instruction
# copy python dependency wheels from python-build-stage
COPY --from=python-build-stage /usr/src/app/wheels  /wheels/

# use wheels to install python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links=/wheels/ /wheels/* \
    && rm -rf /wheels/

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start
RUN chmod +x /start


COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/worker/start /start-celeryworker
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celeryworker
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/beat/start /start-celerybeat
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celerybeat
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/flower/start /start-flower
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-flower
RUN chmod +x /start-flower


# copy application code to WORKDIR
COPY . ${APP_HOME}

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

local.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  uniqued_local_postgres_data: {}
  uniqued_local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: uniqued_local_django
    container_name: uniqued_local_django
    platform: linux/x86_64
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: uniqued_production_postgres
    container_name: uniqued_local_postgres
    volumes:
      - uniqued_local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      - uniqued_local_postgres_data_backups:/backups:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  docs:
    image: uniqued_local_docs
    container_name: uniqued_local_docs
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/docs/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
    volumes:
      - ./docs:/docs:z
      - ./config:/app/config:z
      - ./uniqued:/app/uniqued:z
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    command: /start-docs

  redis:
    image: redis:6
    container_name: uniqued_local_redis

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: uniqued_local_celeryworker
    container_name: uniqued_local_celeryworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: uniqued_local_celerybeat
    container_name: uniqued_local_celerybeat
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    ports: []
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    image: uniqued_local_flower
    container_name: uniqued_local_flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    command: /start-flower
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and kudos for what is an excellent first question.